# ExpressJS and Firebase Auth, beginner queries

Tags: express, authentication, firebase-authentication, login-control

I am trying to learn ExpressJS, so I creating a simple website with login functionality...
I want to use Firebase for the accounts and database(Firestore)

My problem is that, Firebase Auth seems to be client-side only and the backend has no idea if the client is logged in or not...
I want to limit the HTML rendered to the client if he is not logged in, but I can't figure out how to check if he is logged in

I know that I can use

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if (!user){
    window.location.replace("/login");
}});
```

on the client side, that doesn't look "Secured" enough to me and I would like to do it in ExpressJS

On firebase documentation I found this about [Verifying ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)
but I don't understand first of all how would I send the token to ExpressJS and second, how would I send it before the request to a route is made...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the ID token to your backend. You then verify the ID token as explained in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients.

You pass the ID token in the request header if your application is a single page app everytime a request is sent.

If you are building a more traditional web app, you can set the ID token via a cookie and retrieve it and check in on your backend with each request. You have to do the following:

1. Proactively refresh the ID token by calling `getIdToken(true)` before the token expires. The token typically lasts an hour. You would need to refresh it before expiration and update the cookie so a redirect will still consider the user signed in.
2. If the user visits your website after a while (longer than an hour), the cookie would be expired, you would redirect to a temporary page where you set `onAuthStateChanged` and if the user is logged in, call `getIdToken()`, update the cookie and redirect to the intended destination, otherwise consider the user signed out.